# how to replace folder name before last right slash by jquery or js (substring?)

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, substring

how to replace folder name before last right slash  by jquery or js (substring?)
for example 

to

and

if "1" is variable  (cause my img item create via foor loop)
1 could be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....................

```
<body>
    <img src="./pic/web_show/1/01.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="./pic/web_show/1/02.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="./pic/web_show/1/03.jpg" alt="">

    <input type="button" id="btn_change_folder_style_seg" value="style seg"></input>
    <input type="button" id="btn_change_folder_style_raw" value="style raw"></input>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#btn_change_folder_style_seg').click(function () {
                var imagePath = $('img');
                imagePath.attr('src', function (index, attr) {
                    if (attr){
                    return attr.replace('1/', '1_seg/');
                    }
                });
            });
            $('#btn_change_folder_style_raw').click(function () {
                var imagePath = $('img');
                imagePath.attr('src', function (index, attr) {
                    if (attr){
                    return attr.replace('1/', '1_raw/');
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `concat` with `index`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn_change_folder_style_seg').click(function() {
    var imagePath = $('img');
    imagePath.attr('src', function(index, attr) {
      if (attr) {
        return attr.replace('1/', index + 1 + '_seg/');
      }
    });
  });
  $('#btn_change_folder_style_raw').click(function() {
    var imagePath = $('img');
    imagePath.attr('src', function(index, attr) {
      if (attr) {
        return attr.replace('1/', index + 1 + '_raw/');
      }
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="./pic/web_show/1/01.jpg" alt="">
<img src="./pic/web_show/1/02.jpg" alt="">
<img src="./pic/web_show/1/03.jpg" alt="">

<input type="button" id="btn_change_folder_style_seg" value="style seg"></input>
<input type="button" id="btn_change_folder_style_raw" value="style raw"></input>
```